# Debugging the 'A non well formed numeric value encountered' error

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a method within a user record that stores Stripe payment intents. However, this method keeps triggering a PHP ErrorException `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

```php
    /**
     * Record a stripe charge
     *
     * @param PaymentIntent $intent
     *
     * @return string
     * @throws Exception
     */

    public function recordStripeCharge(PaymentIntent $intent)
    {
        // get our existing charge meta
        $aData = get_user_meta($this->getID(), '_stripe_charges', true) ?: [];
        $date = new DateTime();

        // update our charge meta with new value
        $aData[$date->format('Ymd-His')] = $intent->id;
        update_user_meta($this->getID(), '_stripe_charges', $aData);

        return $intent->id;
    }
```

So the error occurs on this line -

```php
$aData[$date->format('Ymd-His')] = $intent->id;
```

However, I can't see why this is happening. `$aData` should be an array of either pre-existing key-value pairs or an empty array. However, when I try and set the item in the array it generates this error?

The key I am trying to build is a string, e.g. `20200310-092650` and when I test that's exactly what is generated.

Hope someone can help!

Thanks,
Chris.

Comment: Check that `$date->format('Ymd-His')` returns correct formatted value.

Comment: @u_mulder - thanks. It outputs as I'd expect, I've amended my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

try to set 'false' instead 'true':

`$aData = get_user_meta($this->getID(), '_stripe_charges', false) ?: [];`

If $single (third value passed) is set to true, does not return an array. I copy the return description of [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/):

```
(mixed) Will be an array if $single is false. Will be value of meta data field if $single is true.
```

Comment: Hi @Nobady, thanks for the answer. The value of the user meta I am loading is a serialized array of data. So if there is a value set, it will return an array anyway. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: @Chris I have never used get_user_meta () but from its reference (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) I seem to understand that if you set $single to false then it returns an array, otherwise (to true) returns a single value.

just for a further try you can take a test:

$ aData = [];
$ aData [$ date-> format ('Ymd-His')] = '123test';

if this works it means that $aData is not an array when it executes get_user_meta ()